# Running make get-monolite-latest, connection to storage.bos.xamarin.com never succeeds

Tags: mono, centos, xamarin

Running

```
make get-monolite-latest
```

on my Centos 6.5 server seems to always give me a connection failure. I've seen this for a few days now:

```
rm -fr /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite-*
mkdir -p /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib
test ! -d /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite || test ! -d /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite.old || rm -fr /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite.old
test ! -d /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite || mv -f /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib/monolite.old
cd /root/mono/mono/mcs/class/lib && { (wget -O- http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-111-latest.tar.gz || curl http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-111-latest.tar.gz) | gzip -d | tar xf - ; }
--2014-06-22 15:01:24--  http://storage.bos.xamarin.com/mono-dist-master/latest/monolite-111-latest.tar.gz
Resolving storage.bos.xamarin.com... 198.0.162.157
Connecting to storage.bos.xamarin.com|198.0.162.157|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

If I leave it then the connection attempts never succeed.

Can I get this file from another source please?

Comment: I've emailed hello@xamarin.com in the hope I get some help with this.

Comment: I got a reply from Xamarin:

'Mono is an open source project sponsored by Xamarin. For general questions related to running an application on an open source Mono release on Windows, Linux, or OS X, superior expertise can be found in the Mono community on Stack Overflow, through the mailing list/forums, or IRC chat:
http://mono-project.com/Community

If this question is related to Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Mono licensing or other Xamarin products, we will do our best to respond to you in a timely manner.'

This wasn't too helpful, but following receipt I found the server was back online :-)

Comment: I'm wondering if I should put the monolite-111-latest.tar.gz file somewhere online, just in case others have issues with storage.bos.xamarin.com in the future...