# Can't install mono on linux

Tags: linux, mono

I'm having trouble building and installing mono. the problem is that the call

> make get-monolite-latest

fails due to invalid url. Anyone knows how to bypass this error?

P.S. I'm using Linux Mint 16

Thanks.

Comment: The [Mono Installation Page](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Installation) describes several ways to install.  Have you tried a different way than the one you describe above?

Comment: You gotta be more specific and give more details. Also, get-monolite-latest isn't a 100% fit solution for everyone. I remember a few time ago i couldn't compile mono that way and now i can

Comment: If you mean while compiling mono; there must be something wrong with the xamarin servers. See: [get-monolite-latest fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352023/running-make-get-monolite-latest-connection-to-storage-bos-xamarin-com-never-su)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is online again; see [my question regarding the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352023/running-make-get-monolite-latest-connection-to-storage-bos-xamarin-com-never-su). It allowed me to complete a Centos install of Mono 3.4.0.